# sudo: preserve non-std file descriptors

Tags: bash, sudo

Long story short: why isn't this (simplified) sample working?

```
root:# sudo -C 3 -u regular-user cat /dev/fd/3 3< /var/log/syslog
cat: /dev/fd/3: No Such file or directory
```

There is a file that contains

```
Defaults closefrom_override
```

in my /etc/sudoers.d

I am using bash 4.2.20 and Debian Wheezy

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`man sudo` says:

> Close all file descriptors greater than **or equal to** *num* before executing a command.

Since you're passing fd 3 to the command, you must specify a number greater than 3 (4 or higher).

In fact, your command now fails with an explicit error message:

```
sudo: closefrom=3: value too small
```